# Puppeteer Won't Click on Element

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs, puppeteer

Trying to get Puppeteer to navigate through my login page which will bring the automated test to the main page of my site. It all works until it reaches 'waitFor('#idSIButton9');'. Puppeteer successfully enters the password and username but can't seem to select the submit button(#idSIButton9). Any idea what might be going wrong here? Let me know if you guys need more info.
Thanks :)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const { defineSupportCode } = require('cucumber')

    defineSupportCode(({ Before, Given, When, Then }) => {
        Before({ timeout: 60 * 1000 }, async function testCase() {

            this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

            this.page = await this.browser.newPage();

            await this.page.setViewport({width: 1024, height: 768});

            await this.page.goto('http://localhost:3000', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

            await this.page.screenshot({ path: 'test_artifacts/img/load.png', fullPage: true });

            await this.page.waitFor('button');

            await this.page.click('button');

            await this.page.waitFor('#i0116');

            await this.page.type('#i0116', 'username');

            await this.page.waitFor('#i0118');

            await this.page.type('#i0118', 'password');

            await this.page.waitFor('#idSIButton9');

            await this.page.click('#idSIButton9');

        })
```

Comment: Maybe it's a typo on that page? Maybe adding a screenshot of that page might let us help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fairly obvious but putting a wait before clicking works with a numeric value:

```
await this.page.waitFor(2000);

await this.page.click('#idSIButton9');

await this.page.waitForNavigation();
```

Comment: The above code snippet worked for me. But now as `waitFor` method is deprecated, I tried using explicit `waitForSelector` or `waitForTimeout` which are not working. Even I tried using hard wait but no luck. Any help please?

Comment: WaitFor() is deprecated, but you can use WaitForTimout() instead.

Answer (score 3):

I seems to find, as the above answer

```
page.waitForNavigation('load')
```

Works well in cases where clicking triggers navigation.